# What is the meaning of mAyA mentioned in the Rudram?

Tags: yajur-veda, maya

Famous hymn Rudram, 11th Anuvaka has the following mantra

> Mantra  16
>
> ये ते सहस्रमयुतं पाशा मृत्यो मर्त्याय हन्तवे ।
>
> तान् यज्ञस्य मायया सर्वानवयजामहे ॥
>
> Mantra 17
>
> मृत्यवे स्वाहा-  मृत्यवे स्वाहा ॥

So what is the maayaa of the yajna ? how is it related to immortality?

Comment: Actions out of lust anger greed attachment and ego is called sin. These 5 are called Maya.

Comment: You should format your question.

Comment: Also which AnuvAka?

Comment: Here "Yajnasya Mayayaa" means with *measure or strength* of good actions. Not illusion. मायया not माया.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I feel that this translation is not correct because mAyayA is the 3rd vibhakti of mAyA which means the mAyA  i.e. shakti OF yajna. Further How come yajnasya mean good actions?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Aurobindo-KApaly ShAstry school, the following is the translation:

> Ye te sahsramayutam pAshA mrityo martyAya hantave |
>
> O Death who kills mortals by hundreds of knots.
>
> TAn yajnasya mAyayA sarvAnava yajAmahe |
>
> I worship him with this subtle (MAyaya) yajnas for protection (ava).

So, it's not MAyA but MAya... and it is meaning subtle..

Another translation provided by [the KAmakoti.org](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotra/Sri%20Rudram%20Anuvakam11.html) is as follows:

> ये ते सहस्रमयुतं पाशा मृत्यो मर्त्याय हन्तवे ।
>  तान् यज्ञस्य मायया
>   सर्वानवयजामहे ॥
>
> Meaning:
>
> मृत्यो-   O Parameswara, the form of Death, मर्त्याय-  all dying
>   creatures,  हन्तवे-  for catching,  ते- your,  सहस्रं- in thousands, 
>   अयुतं-  in tens of thousands,  ये- which,  पाशाः- ropes (and similar
>   instruments of torture are there),  तान् सर्वान्-  all of them, 
>   यज्ञस्य मायया-   with the strength of our good actions,  अवयजामहे- 
>   put aside.

Comment: I feel that this translation is not correct because mAyayA is the 3rd vibhakti of mAyA which means the mAyA  i.e. shakti OF yajna. Further How come yajnasya mean good actions?

Comment: You mean the 2nd one? I am more ok with first one.. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: i am more interested in knowing meaning of maayayaa from Sanskrit point of view. I feel its third vibhakti of maayaa. Which means that shakti of yajna is said as maayaa here

Comment: MAya means "subtle".. so it is saying "with these inner (subtle) Yajnas" ... that's the way the first quote translates.. the 2nd quote falls into Bhavartha kind of translation.. it does not seem word to word to me.. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: Kamakoti wrong meaning